# How do I convert the weekday of a particular date?

Tags: python, html, calendar, weekday

I've been stuck for hours; could someone please help me figure this out?

Create a mini-web-application that tells the user the weekday of a particular date.

To determine the day of the week, you can use a function from the calendar module. The weekday function can be called like this:

weekday = calendar.weekday(y, m, d)
… assuming you have the year, month, and day in variables y, m, and d. This will put an integer 0–6 in the variable weekday, where 0 is Monday, 1 is Tuesday, and so on.

Use a series of if statements to produce output like this on the generated page (with the appropriate weekday, of course—this is what you'd produce if the weekday was 0):

This is my first post, and it won't let me upload my code because the formatting is different on here but I have the first part (import.cgi, import calendar, and
form = cgi.FieldStorage() part) then the content type and doctype, then CGI script

then the int codes

then the if statements for the weekday part

```
import.cgi
import calendar
form = cgi.FieldStorage()

#CGI Script 
print 
year = int(form.getvalue("year")) 
month = int(form.getvalue("month")) 
day = int(form.getvalue("day")) 
weekday = calendar.weekday(y, m, d) 
if weekday == 0: 
    print ("<p> That's monday </p>") 
if weekday == 1: 
    print ("<p> That's tuesday </p>") 
if weekday == 2: 
    print ("<p> That's wednesday </p>") 
if weekday == 3: 
    print ("<p> That's thursday </p>") 
if weekday == 4: 
    print ("<p> That's friday </p>") 
if weekday == 5: 
    print ("<p> That's saturday </p>") 
if weekday == 6: 
    print ("<p> That's sunday </p>")
```

Comment: It dsnt let you post code on the first post?? Post it as text, we can format it

Comment: #CGI Script
print
year = int(form.getvalue("year"))
month = int(form.getvalue("month"))
day = int(form.getvalue("day"))

weekday = calendar.weekday(y, m, d)
if weekday == 0:
    print ("<p> That's monday </p>")
if weekday == 1:
    print ("<p> That's tuesday </p>")
if weekday == 2: 
    print ("<p> That's wednesday </p>")
if weekday == 3:
    print ("<p> That's thursday </p>")
if weekday == 4:
    print ("<p> That's friday </p>")
if weekday == 5:
    print ("<p> That's saturday </p>")
if weekday == 6:
    print ("<p> That's sunday </p>")

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation.  [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) applies here.  In particular, what output *do* you get when you run this?  The code appears reasonably correct.  Show your actual output, including what you got from your attempts to debug.

Comment: It appears that you don't know how to format code in this environment.  Select the block of code, then click on the {} icon on top of the editing window.  This provides blank lines to separate and indents 4 spaces, which is the meta-code for a code block.

Answer (score 0):

Starting from your code, I had to replace y,m,d by year,month,day as arguments of calendar.weekday to get it to work. Is it the point where you were stuck ?

```
import calendar
year = 2015 
month = 12 
day = 3 
weekday = calendar.weekday(year, month, day) 
if weekday == 0: 
   print ("<p> That's monday </p>") 
if weekday == 1: 
   print ("<p> That's tuesday </p>") 
if weekday == 2: 
   print ("<p> That's wednesday </p>") 
if weekday == 3: 
   print ("<p> That's thursday </p>") 
if weekday == 4: 
   print ("<p> That's friday </p>") 
if weekday == 5: 
   print ("<p> That's saturday </p>") 
if weekday == 6: 
   print ("<p> That's sunday </p>")
```

Comment: YES THANK YOU SO MUCH. I MANAGED TO FIGURE IT OUT THANK YOU FROM THE BOTTOM OF MY HEART!

Answer (score 0):

Python likes to provide things you're likely to need...so we can use what they have in their libraries.  Try this script:

```
import time
t = (2015, 12, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0) # t is Dec 3 2015 -- replace with whatever you like
q = time.mktime (t)                 #convert to floating point rep, which is needed by...
r = time.gmtime (q)                 #convert to struct time, which is needed by...
print (time.strftime ("%A", r))     #formats time as a string.  %A means "weekday"
```

This will print Thursday, since 2015-12-3 is Thursday.

Adapt as needed to your own script.

For more on time.strftime, see http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/time_strftime.htm .